# Does a Fire Elemental inflict fire damage without attacking?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, movement

I am playing a level 10 Circle of the Moon druid. In combat against trolls, I transformed into a fire elemental.

Does entering an enemy-occupied space cause the enemy to take fire damage, without me attacking? I thought it was automatic, like an aura, but my DM says it requires an attack.

Answer (score 13):

## YES, it does NOT require an attack

The relevant part of a Fire Elemental's "Fire Form" ability reads like this:

> In addition, the elemental can enter a hostile creature's space and stop there. The first time it enters a creature's space on a turn, that creature takes 5 (1d10) fire damage and catches fire.

Entering the space of another creature is different from stopping there or attacking. The rule specifically states that simply entering the space as part of your movement causes them to take 5 (1d10) fire damage.

This is different from the damage inflicted for touching or attacking the elemental, which would not trigger in this scenario. It's important to distinguish the 2 sources of damage because they function differently (Movement one is only once per turn).

There is no rule about inflicting fire damage specifically by attacking.